# javascript jquery help

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroller

I am trying to find a good vertical text scroller. Basically what I want is a scroller that goes vertically but is continuous (meaning the area is never empty while waiting for the text). I can use either javascript or jquery. I have searched around the net but I have not found a good one. I want it to constantly scroll without doing it at set intervals. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Sounds like you want jScroller2

http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/endless/

This loops continuously.